# How to mock AngularJS $resource with $promise.then in jasmine specs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I use `$resource` to set up some API calls, and while testing I have adopted the general approach of injecting `$q`and then doing

`mockMyService.doSomethingAsync.andReturnValue($q.when(successResponse))`

This has been working out pretty well, however, I have a method that looks like the following:

```coffee
# MyService
MyService.doSomethingAsync(params).$promise.then ->
    $scope.isLoading = false

# MyService Spec
mockMyService = 
  doSomethingAsync: jasmine.createSpy('doSomethingAsync')

it 'calls service #doSomethingAsync', ->
  inject ($q) -> mockMyService.doSomethingAsync.and.returnValue($q.when(response))
  controller.methodThatWrapsServiceCall()
  scope.$apply()

  expect(mockMyService.doSomethingAsync).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

and unfortunately the **mocking strategy outlined above doesn't seem to work when a `$promise.then` is chained at the end.** I end up with the following error:

```bash
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'MyService.doSomethingAsync(params).$promise.then')
```

Methods that simply end with `doSomethingAsync().$promise` pass the tests  without issues using this mocking strategy.

(Other info: These are Jasmine tests run with Karma and PhantomJS)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, figured it out!

I just changed my mock to return `and.returnValue( { $promise: $q.when(response) } )`