# $resource not resolving in test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to use `apiSearch.get().then(func(){...})`  I have it working in my tests, but I can't get the data when I use that same method in my controller.  Is it even possible to use .then() with a returned resource?  If not, is there another solution I can use in my in place of my controller or test code?

***service.js***

```
angular.module('app').factory('apiSearch', ['$resource', '$log',
    function ($resource, $log) {

        return $resource('api/search/:value', {}, {
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false,
                cache: true

            }
        });
    }
])
```

***pageService.js***

```
/*** this works when I test it in the browser but makes my test fail ***/

apiSearch.get({value: 'thisvalue'}, function (res) {
    $state.go('storefront.home');

}, function (err) {
    $state.go('not-found');
})




/*** this works for my test but fails in the browser ***/

apiSearch.get({value: 'thisvalue'}).then(function (res) {
    $state.go('storefront.home');

}, function (err) {
    $state.go('not-found');
})
```

***test.js***

```
it("Should ", function(){

    resolveData = 'itemName'
    deferred.resolve(resolveData);

    spyOn(apiSearch, "get").and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
    $scope.$digest();
    expect($state.current.name).toEqual('storefront.home');

});
```

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241329/angularjs-unit-testing-resolving-promises

Comment: Found this as well.   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234920/how-to-mock-angularjs-resource-with-promise-then-in-jasmine-specs
This is more for use with $resource rather than callbacks like the first link.